# In typeorm with nestjs, ormconfig.json is not getting detected

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config

I am relatively new to using typeorm. I am trying to separate the ormconfig.json for production and development environment but I keep getting this error:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: Cannot find connection default because its not defined in any orm configuration files.
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**database.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection, getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () =>
        Object.assign(
          await getConnectionOptions(
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'prod' : 'dev',
          ),
        ),
    }),
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})

export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(connection: Connection) {
    if (connection.isConnected) console.log('DB Connected Successfully!');
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    DatabaseModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      playground: true,
      debug: true,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
    }),
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**ormconfig.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "dev",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "database": "yourcar",
    "entities": ["dist/**/entities/*{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging":true,
    "migrationsRun":true,
    "migrations":["dist/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir":"src/database/migrations"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "prod",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "database": "yourcar",
    "entities": ["dist/**/entities/*{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": false,
    "migrationsRun":true,
    "migrations":["dist/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir":"src/database/migrations"
    }
  }
]
```

I thought the ormconfig.json gets automatically detected at the root directory so I tried using just one environment and changed database.module.ts to:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig)],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(connection: Connection) {
    if (connection.isConnected) {
      console.log('CONNECTED SUCCESS');
    }
  }
}
```

but this also doesn't work so I guess ormconfig is not getting detected only. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NestJS/config](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration) with `.env` file for declare your BDD config. And in your `database.module.ts` you can set this config.

Example :

```js
// app.module.ts
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true,
            cache: true,
            load: config,
            envFilePath: getEnvFiles(),
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// src/config/database.config.ts

export default registerAs('database', () => ({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
    user: process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'root',
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE || 'test',
    ...
}));
```

```js
// database.module.ts

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get<string>('database.host'),
                port: configService.get<number>('database.port'),
                username: configService.get<string>('database.user'),
                password: configService.get<string>('database.password'),
                database: configService.get<string>('database.database'),
                logger: new CustomORMLogger(new AdvancedConsoleLogger('all'), configService),
                logging: configService.get<boolean>('database.logging'),
                entities: configService.get<string[]>('database.entities'),
                migrations: configService.get<string[]>('database.migrations'),
                synchronize: true,
            }),
        }),
    ],
    exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
    constructor(connection: Connection) {
        if (connection.isConnected) console.log('DB Connected Successfully!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It didn't exactly answer my question but did make me understand a bit about handling env variables in nestjs w typeorm. I initally wanted to know how to setup and use dev and prod configs from ormconfig.json like in this vid: 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ELH8CT4J0A&t=26678s . Somehow even by following the steps there, the program didn't seem to be detecting the ormconfig.json

Comment: Indeed concerning the reading of the ormconfig file this is strange ... I do not understand why indeed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the support for `ormconfig.json` was dropped in `typeorm@0.3.0`. See [breaking-changes](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1).

NestJS shows an alternative approach via `ConfigService` and `.env` file [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases):

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('HOST'),
    port: +configService.get('PORT'),
    username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
    password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('DATABASE'),
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```